# Looking for shipping information leaving England in September 1879 for Japan

Tags: 19th-century, england, manifest, japan

I am looking for shipping information about one James Main Dixon (1856 (Paisley)-1933 (Los Angeles)) who left England in September 1879 for Yokohama, Japan. He stayed in Japan from 1880 through 1892 June and then moved to America. First, lived at St. Louis, Missouri and then California.

Can anybody guide me how can I find which ship, on which date, from which port of England he boarded and on which date he arrived in Yokohama? in Japan ?

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy & Family History SE! A couple of questions: What makes you say he left from England? Could he not have departed from a Scottish port, since he was born in Scotland? Have you traced his movements up until 1879, as this could be an indication of which port he was likely to leave from? Any family members with him? Occupation and purpose of travel? These details could help track him down. Also, how do you know he left in Sep 1879 – that seems very specific considering you don't know where he travelled from?

Comment: What was his purpose in traveling to Japan? If he was sent by an employer, that company's records might have information, and their head office might be located near a likely port of departure.

Comment: @bgwiehle - if he's [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Main_Dixon) James Main Dixon, then he went over there to teach. That's a poorly sourced Wiki though, and some of it looks worth double-checking.

Comment: @HarryVervet - the above link states that he graduated from St Andrews in 1879, so he could well have sailed from Scotland in the same year.